# GNOME 3 Not Logging Out on Laptop Close

Tags: gnome, session

I'm having trouble trying to set GNOME to logout my current users on a laptop close and after x minutes of activity. I've tried running

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

directly from terminal, but I'm constantly getting parsing errors upon startup. I've looked at various other posts for solutions on how to fix that problem but none have provided a solution. I was looking at the gnome-tweak-tool code on GitHub to try and set the settings manually in my

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

file, but that also didn't work. Has anyone had a similar issue? I just switched to Ubuntu from Arch and didn't have this problem when running GNOME 3 on Arch. Perhaps this could be from a Unity process that still controls the logout upon lid close?

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 and had originally done the Ubuntu Unity installation. Not sure if that makes a difference given that it's not the Ubuntu GNOME distribution.

I get the following errors:

```
INFO : GSettings missing key org.gnome.nautilus.desktop (key computer-icon-visible) 

(gnome-tweak-tool:4461): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to set text from markup due to error parsing markup: Error on line 1 char 190: Element 'span' was closed, but the currently open element is 'alt' 
(gnome-tweak-tool:4461): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to set text from markup due to error parsing markup: Error on line 1 char 190: Element 'span' was closed, but the currently open element is 'alt'
```

running version 3.10 of gnome-tweak-tool.

Comment: I edited my original post. Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Those are just infos and warnings. I have no idea, why it doesn't start.

Comment: Ok, well is there anything else I could try or am I just stuck with it? I really don't want to have to go back to Unity or reinstall Ubuntu GNOME.